# Take action after the main form is shown in a Qt desktop application

Tags: c++, forms, qt, show

In Delphi I often made an `OnAfterShow` event for the main form.  The standard `OnShow()` for the form would have little but a `postmessage()` which would cause the `OnafterShow` method to be executed.

I did this so that sometimes lengthy data loading or initializations would not stop the normal loading and showing of the main form.

I'd like to do something similar in a Qt application that will run on a desktop computer either Linux or Windows.

What ways are available to me to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override `showEvent()` of the window and call the function you want to be called with a single shot timer :

```
void MyWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *)
{
    QTimer::singleShot(50, this, SLOT(doWork());
}
```

This way when the windows is about to be shown, `showEvent` is triggered and the `doWork` slot would be called within a small time after it is shown.

You can also override the `eventFilter` in your widget and check for `QEvent::Show` event :

```
bool MyWidget::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event)
{
    if(obj == this && event->type() == QEvent::Show)
    {
        QTimer::singleShot(50, this, SLOT(doWork());
    }

    return false;
}
```

When using event filter approach, you should also install the event filter in the constructor by:

```
this->installEventFilter(this);
```

Comment: Thank you Nejat.  Reading the docs (here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#showEvent ) it seems like the event willl happen before the window is (first) shown.  Am I right?   I'm looking to do work after the window is first shown.

Comment: Yeah it will be called before the window is shown. You can use a single shot timer to call a function after the widget is shown. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Indeed non-spontaneous events are delivered before the widget is shown. That's for example when you call `show` pragmatically.

Comment: That works, even with very small interval value.  Thank you.  It seems wrong to use a timer for something like this, though. But it is the only way I've found that works so far.

Comment: I've also tried to find how to achieve exactly the same goal, but among all of solutions I've tried only this `QTimer` hack works. If anyone is aware how to do this _proper_ way, it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it without a timer using Paint event. Works for me at least on Windows.

```
// MainWindow.h
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    ...
    bool event(QEvent *event) override;
    void functionAfterShown();
    ...
    bool functionAfterShownCalled = false;
    ...
}

// MainWindow.cpp
bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *event)
{
    const bool ret_val = QMainWindow::event(event);
    if(!functionAfterShownCalled && event->type() == QEvent::Paint)
    {
        functionAfterShown();
        functionAfterShownCalled = true;
    }
    return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: Cunning.  Thanks.