# Is there any Qt SIGNAL something like windowFinishedLoading?

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any Qt SIGNAL for doing some actions after the Qt application window has finished loading. For example, in ajax, we have some functions like “ajaxComplete or ajaxSuccess or done” etc. after which we can do something else?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "loading" ? Is that when the window is shown?

Comment: Yes, I mean when the window is shown.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458639/take-action-after-the-main-form-is-shown-in-a-qt-desktop-application/28459563#28459563