# Is there any QML window UI fully constructed signal?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534531/is-there-any-qt-signal-something-like-windowfinishedloading), but it is only about QWidget based project. What about `ApplicationWindow` components in QML?

Comment: Did you try `Component.onCompleted`?

Comment: @ixSci yes, for `ApplicationWindow` component and for its children. But it is called before the whole UI is loaded.

Comment: Do you have dynamically loaded elements in your UI?

Comment: @cmannett85 in general yes. But it is not important. I want to see a least static elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've connected to `frameSwapped` signal of the main top-level `QQuickWindow` of my application. It is called right after each repainting is done. So, after first repainting, my slot would be called, and I will start to really load the data (what is rather slow). Inside this slot I'm destroying this connection, so I don't slow down the application.

```
//main.cpp
QQuickWindow* mainWindow =
    qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(engine.rootObjects().first());
QMetaObject::Connection loadingFinished =
    QObject::connect(mainWindow, SIGNAL(frameSwapped()),
                     &controller, SLOT(construct()));
controller.setConnection(loadingFinished);

//Controller.cpp
void Controller::construct() // this is slot
{
    // some really long operation
    disconnect(*m_loadingFinished);
}
```

Hope it will be helpful for someone.