# How to call a user method after show method in qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void foo();
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_1_clicked();

private:
   Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    MainWindow 
    w.show();       //It display blank window without any buttons or content
    w.foo();       //It execute before the window is rendered 

    return a.exec(); 
}
```

`w.show()` invokes `MainWindow` constructor. I would like to call function foo after the window is rendered completely. So, that I can perform actions on it. But after `w.show()` it looks like image1 and then calls foo which can't do anything because there is no interface. I removed `w.foo()` and set the break point at `w.show()`. While debugging at `w.show()` it look like below image1 and after `return a.exec()` it looks like image2 with full interface. The code for all these functions are written in **mainwindow.cpp** and gui in **mainwindow.ui**.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUtbE.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leORb.jpg)

**EDIT**
foo function

```
void MainWindow::foo()
{
    ui->statusbar->clearMessage();
    ec.pause();
    ec.start();   //start thread
    ec.wait();    //wait until thread ends
    new TreeOperations(); 
}
```

Comment: [Take action after the main form is shown in a Qt desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458639/take-action-after-the-main-form-is-shown-in-a-qt-desktop-application)

Comment: @AdrianMole No.

Comment: Try calling `w.repaint()` after `show()` and before `foo()`. This should cause the window to paint itself immediately.