# Copying QGraphicScenes in and out of QGraphicsView

Tags: qt

I have a QGraphicsView and a rather complicated QGraphicsScene which should be displayed in the view and the whole thing runs on a rather slow device. Now when the user switches between other dialogs and the dialog with the view, the whole app freezes for 2 seconds or so before showing the dialog with the view.

So I experimented a bit and in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356121/how-to-call-function-after-window-is-shown) I found out that I can just do

```
void MainDialog::showEvent(QShowEvent * event){
    if (ui->graphicsView->scene() != NULL){
        ui->graphicsView->scene()->clear();
    }
    QTimer::singleShot(50, this, SLOT(updateDiagram()));
}
```

And in the updateDiagram() method I paint the stuff on the scene, and it feels much more responsive now, because now the dialog with the view is shown immediately and then the diagram shows up a bit later, which is fine with me.

But it feels wrong to redraw the entire complicated diagram every time the user goes back to the main dialog. So i figured I could just save the scene and only redraw it when the data has changed. But how to do it?

I tried this - but I get blank scenes for every run but the first - that's logical because the clear() in showEvent goes to the scene in the view which points to the same place as m_savedScene so that's cleared now.

```
void MainDialog::updateDiagram(){
    if(dataChanged){
         QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
         /*draw complicated stuff*/
         /*save for future use*/
         m_savedScene = scene; //Line 6
         view.setScene(scene); //Line 7
    } else {
         view.setScene(m_savedScene); //Line 9
    }           
}
```

So now I have 2 questions.

1. In line 6 and line 9 I think I need to save/use a copy of the scene so the scene in the view does not point to the same object as m_savedScene so the m_savedScene doesn't get cleared, but how do I do that, given that QGraphicsScene doesn't seem to have a copy constructor?
2. In line 7 do I need to take care of destroying the scene that was in the view previously? Since the view doesn't take ownership of the scenes it gets via setScene(), I'm guessing the view won't do it, but how can I do it?

Comment: Line 6 and line 9: You think wrong. It has a reason that QGraphicsScene has not public copyconstructor: It is a QObject. And QObject are strictly non copyable. You can stop looking in that direction.

Comment: @Greenflow: Im new to Qt (and to c++) so thanks for that information. Any idea what I should try instead?

Comment: Not enough info. I don't know how your scene looks like and what changes when your data changes. So ideas would only be baseless speculations. However, do your really have to destroy your scene every time data changed? This is of course costly.

Comment: And question 2. You can do: QGraphicsScene *oldScene = view.scene(); view.setScene(newScene); oldScene->deleteLater().

Comment: But if you delete oldScene, m_savedScene becomes invalid, too. The whole 'saving scenes' does not make much sense here. If possible keep one scene and update only items, which changed... if possible.

Comment: @Greenflow: That's what I tried at first - the data doesn't change that often, so I just didn't do anything to the view and the scene - but then every time the dialog with the view becomes visible, it takes 2 seconds before it's actually shown. It seems it has to do the rendering again and again when the dialog with the view becomes visible - is there any way to change that? Btw, the dialog around the view is just a few labels and buttons, but the scene in the view has some 1000 lines.

Comment: See, I don't know what you tried. But you made a mistake. If you have a stacked widget, or a tabwidget and use it to switch to another widget and back, there is no reason that your scene is redrawn. I stop here. If I am allowed to give you an advice: Next time you seek help, show actual code. Nothing is more tiring than asking for necessary info one comment after another.

Comment: @Greenflow: Those are snippets of the actual code, but next time I'll try to make a minimal working example. Just thought it wouldn't help much in this case. Guess i was wrong. Thanks anyway. I'll read up on stacked widget and try to find a setup where my scene doesn't get redrawn every time it's shown.

Comment: @Greenflow I actually solved my problem a long while ago thanks to your hints. 1. I made a connection from a dataChanged signal in my class that represents the data to the updateDiagram method so it gets redrawn if the data actually changed. 2. I removed the whole stuff in the showEvent method, so I don't clear or redraw anything on show. 3. I rewrote the updateDiagram method a bit. It now just does delete m_savedScene; m_savedScene = myDataPainter.drawScene(); view.setScene(m_savedScene); I'd just delete my question now, unless you think it'd be helpful if I turn this comment into an answer.