# How to show dialog when main window became visible for the very first time in Qt widgets application?

Tags: c++, qt

I have Qt widgets application that has to authorize user with web service request before he can use the program. If user can not sign in for any reason, I have to exit the application.

.NET Framework implements `Load` event for that: when user sees window for the very firt time (the keyword here is "user sees"), it is possible to display dialog; if dialog result is not OK, we call close on main application window.

With Qt, we can override `showEvent`. However, it fires before user really can see main window. When I create dialog in `showEvent`, it appears without main window, and when I close main window in `showEvent`, it doesn't close (because it is not opened at the moment) and appears later event if user failed to sign in. It appears even after `QApplication::quit()` call.

My question is: is there a way to receive exactly the same functionality as in .NET Framework/Windows API and get event fired when user really sees window and not when he "may be sees something or will see soon"? It is possible to start timer from `showEvent` to get similar effect, but I think it is not professional, because you never know what may happend in user computer (may be its CPU works on 100% now), and you can not have real guarantee that timer will show dialog at correct moment.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356121/how-to-call-function-after-window-is-shown

Answer (score 1):

I would try to create MainWindow and hide() it be default. The only widget to be shown at startup should be then the Login-Dialog. I would connect the successful login with the show() slot of the QMainWindow and the login failure - with the quit slot of the application.

Comment: good points. just no need to create the mainwindow in the first place. You can use a custom slot to create it rather than show.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like this in my main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    LoginDialog dialog;
    if(!dialog.exec()){
        return 1;
    }
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

that (of course) after having `LoginDialog` defined to inherit from `QDialog` and `MainWindow` defined to inherit from `QMainWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

Create the main dialog at application startup, and only create the main window when the service responds positively.

You don't really need to dig deep in the event handlers.