# Where do I define variables/objects such as QRegularExpression to be used throughout my Qt Widgets application?

Tags: c++, qt, oop, methods, qwidget

I am trying to formalize a few regex expressions so I can use them more conveniently throughout my Qt Widget-based application. I can define them just fine inside a slot, but I can't figure out where to define them for a wider scope.

Usually I can declare a simple variable in the class header of mainwindowname and I won't face any issues.

I ran into two issues with this, one being values that need a process to be initialized (such an array that needs to be initialized, à la `int a[i]=i for x` between `foo` and `bar`), and the other being `QRegularExpression`. I can define either of those in different functions/slots, but I can't figure out where to put them to be able to work throughout the application. I can't initialize them like I could an `int` or a `QString`.

I understand by digging through the documentation (and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356121/how-to-call-function-after-window-is-shown/56852841)) that it may have something to do with `QShowEvent()` and adding these functions to the "show event" of the main window. I don't understand what the scope is of anything defined here though.

My (tenuous) understanding is that the `QRegularExpression re("things")` thing (is it a method(?)) is effectively called like a function, which is why it doesn't sit in the header file, which doesn't "execute". Something to do with how it is constructed.

I'm still very much a novice especially in the realm of "proper" OOP, so I may be missing some obvious things here. Perhaps a more experienced programmer would make a class for the text structures I want to use with these regex functions.

`mainwindowname.h`:

```
//#include <all the things>

enum exampleenum {fo, oo, ba, r};

class mainwindowname:public QMainWindow
{

Q_OBJECT

public: ...

private slots: ...

private:

...

QRegularExpression re("things", QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption);

//this line doesn't work here

exampleenum foofoo = fo;
int exampleint = 1;
QString qfoo;

//all three of these work

}

#endif // MAINWINDOWNAME_H
```

and `mainwindowname.cpp`:

```
#include <mainwindowname.h>

void mainwindowname::on_thing_happened()
{
QRegularExpression re("things", QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption);

//this will work here
}
```

Comment: `QRegularExpression re("things")` is not a method, it defines an object `re` of class `QRegularExpression` using it's constructor (or one of its constructors).

Answer (score 0):

Do u mean you want a `constructor`?

These two methods are equivalent

```
class A
{

    int exampleint = 1;

};
```

```
class A
{
    A(){
        exampleint=1;
    }
    int exampleint;

};
```

Comment: I can’t construct a QRegularExpression outside of a slot is my issue.

Comment: construct it by writing ```class A {
    QRegularExpression re;
    A():re("things", QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption){}
};```?

Comment: I can write ```QRegularExpression re; ``` just fine after the ```Q_OBJECT``` macro, but where does ```A():re("things", QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption){}``` go? I can't put it below the other statement, or in ```public:``` or ```private:```, without ```expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers``` and ```invalid use of non-static data member 're'```